# Custom Post Type & Meta Box - Displaying meta box information on front end?

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, front-end

I've created a custom post type "projects" that has a meta box for additional information (client name, type of project, budget, etc). I'd like to be able to display this information on the front-end.

The custom post type is available to be added to custom menus if desired ('show_in_nav_menus' => true), but when you view each project, all you see is the title and the description.

Ideally, I'd like the meta data to show with the title and description in whatever theme that is being used for the site, but I don't know if that's possible.

Is there a way to display the meta box information on the front-end without having to either (a) touch the theme files (since themes can change so I don't want to do that) or (b) calling my own function that returns my own page template for the projects (because then it won't use the theme that is active)?

Thanks!

ETA - This is all done within my plugin.

Comment: Take a look at `get_post_custom()`.

Comment: Thanks, I have retrieved the meta box data to display. But how do I get it in the content area through my plugin? I'm using wp_head in my add_filter at the moment to see what I'm echoing out, but obviously I want it within the content area after the title.

Comment: Nevermind, this has been solved. Use 'the_content' of course. :)

Comment: Add this as answer. You can mark it as solution later, so the Q doesn't stay open. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I tried to earlier, but I had to wait to be allowed to do so.

Comment: Just add it and mark it as solution later. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Inside a function, retrieve meta box field values using get_post_custom_values() and added it to $content passed to the function. Use 'the_content' in the add_filter.